# Joomla 2.5 MVC Model prepareTable function

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

while developing a MVC Component, I'm faced with the following problem: Before saving the posted data from the default.php, some data should be revised, if necessary. From what I know so far, the protected Function prepareTable(&$table) in the specific Model should cover my need. I started with a very simple approach, as follows:

```
protected function prepareTable(&$table){

$table=$this->getTable();

$table->image="HelloWorld";

}
```

My expectation is, that after submitting the template a specific field in my table has now the value "HelloWorld", but it isn't.

Perhaps, someone could give me an advice how to handle the prepareTable() function?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything else is setup correctly the `prepareTable(&$table)` method already has the table object passed into it.

Generally a `prepareTable()` in your class wouldn't `getTable()`, as you replace the `$table` being passed in which already has the row data bound to it. By replacing it you effectively decouple from the work already done.

I would remove that line your method looks like:

```
protected function prepareTable(&$table){

    $table->image="HelloWorld";

}
```

If you look at the simplest implementation of `prepareTable()` in the Joomla core files, in `com_banners` you will see something very similar to your method;

```
/**
 * Prepare and sanitise the table data prior to saving.
 *
 * @param   JTable  A JTable object.
 * @since   1.6
 */
protected function prepareTable(&$table)
{
    $table->name = htmlspecialchars_decode($table->name, ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Comment: Glad, to help, to help others could you mark the answer as correct.